# HttpRequest gives 500 error

Tags: apex, error, httprequest

I have an APEX class with code to request a token from https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token. This code works on Development and Acceptance, but is not working on Production.
This is de code I use:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
req.setEndpoint('https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
req.setBody('grant_type=password'+'&client_id=xxx'+'&client_secret=xxx'+'&username=username'+'&password=password+token');

Http h = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = h.send(req);

String token = '';

if (res.getStatusCode() >= 200 && res.getStatusCode() < 300) {
    Map<String, Object> m =  (Map<String, Object>)
    JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
    token = string.valueOf(m.get('access_token'));
} else {
    system.debug('### error: '+res.getBody());
    system.debug('### endpoint: '+req.getEndPoint());
    system.debug('### statuscode: '+res.getStatusCode());
    system.debug('### status: '+res.getStatus());
}
```

I've already checked the credentials with the program Postman, and that works. But when I perform this code from a Community visualforce page, it returns the following error with the error code 500 and status Server Error:

---

> An internal server error has occurred
>   An error has occurred while processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem. If you believe you have additional information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the error, please contact [Salesforce Support](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/hthome). Please indicate the URL of the page you were requesting, any error id shown on this page as well as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience. 
> Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using salesforce.com!
>   
>   An internal server error has occurred
>   
>   An error has occurred while processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem. If you believe you have additional information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the error, please contact [Salesforce Support](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/hthome). Please indicate the URL of the page you were requesting, any error id shown on this page as well as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience. 
> Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using salesforce.com!
>   
>   Error ID: 987822762-193111 (-678364909)

---

Is this some kind of setting in SalesForce? Or maybe a rights issue?

Comment: does it also fails when you run the code from developer console? Long back once, i had similar issue where in code was failing from apex class without any proper error message, but gave more descriptive message when I ran from developer console. Also any useful information in the response?

Comment: Can you make it work via postman? also do you have single-sign on enabled?

Comment: Is the password the same in your different environments? Does it by any chance contain a % character? That's used in url encoding, so that might throw some kind of error because then it cannot figure out what is what.

Comment: `Error ID: 987822762-193111 (-678364909)` implies a gack and is best resolved by calling support (hopefully you have premier support)